# How do I 'unembed' embedded word document fonts?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, embedded-fonts

I have just transferred a word document from one computer to another. It had embedded fonts saved with it. I would like to know how to 'unembed' the fonts **and install them** on my computer.

The reason for doing this is that when I copy text from another document I can't change its font to that of the embedded font.

Comment: You don't have to unembed the embedded fonts. When someone sends you a word document written in a font that is not installed in your computer, then the document will be just crippled. So they can embed fonts, so it is also viewable in your computer. It also includes a copy of the font file in the word document. As it shows the characters in the document correctly, then there is no need to unembed it and it is not also possible. Because the font copy is hidden in the document and you can't unembed it.

Comment: Removing the embedded fonts  **is** possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Wasif, you do not need to unembed the embedded fonts.

Please go to File > Option > Save, check the box of "Embed fonts in the file". This setting is persistent for a single document, meaning that when you save a document, the settings related to font embedding are saved with it.

If you want to install these embedded fonts, you need to download these corresponding fonts first. More information, please refer to "[Add a font](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1)".

Comment: I have edited the question to explain my reasoning

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to know how to 'unembed' the fonts and install them on my computer.

First you should install the required fonts on your computer.

To find the list of embedded fonts you can try using `FontList` by Raymond Mercier It will also allow you to extract the fonts to disk.

> The document format created by Word 2007 is essentially a collection of XML files, so totally different from that created by earlier versions of Word. Nevertheless Fontlist works in much the same way. One big difference however concerns the embedded fonts. **Any fonts that are embedded can now be downloaded to the disk**.

<sup>Emphasis mine. I've no idea whether FontList works with newer versions of Word.</sup>

Source: [Fontlist for listing fonts in MS Word, Wordperfect, etc](http://www.raymondm.co.uk/Fontlist6.htm)

Then, to remove the embedded fonts:

> If you want to remove the embedding, you can turn off the Embed setting in the File > Options dialog box and save the file. Then, once you close and re-open the file, a different font is substituted for the font that had been embedded previously.

Source: [Embed fonts in documents or presentations - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-fonts-in-documents-or-presentations-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc)